# Given the number of digits for $n!$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n \geq 7$, find the value of $n$.

Tags: factorial

I've seen lots of problems about finding the number of digits of $n!$ so I'm just wondering: is there an approach to do the opposite of this process?

An example would be: given the number of digits for $n!$ is $6$, then the value for $n$ would be $9$ since $n! = 362880$, and the number of digits of $n!$ is exactly $6$.

Comment: Well, no, for the stupid reason that $5! = 120$ and $6! = 720$ have the same numbers of digits.  However, for $n \geq 6$, this doesn't happen again, so maybe restrict your question to big enough $n$s...

Comment: What is "this" process?  It looks like guessing.

Comment: Stirling's formula might be helpful.

Comment: BTW, see http://oeis.org/A034886

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is possible to estimate $n$**. If you take a number $A$ in base $10$, then $\log_{10}{A}$ is roughly the number of digits $A$ has, i.e.
$$A=a_k10^k+a_{k-1}10^{k-1}+...+a_1 10 + a_0, a_i\in \{0,1,...,9\}, a_k\ne0$$
then
$$k\leq \log_{10}{A} < k+1 \tag{1}$$
Now, let's consider 
$$n!=A \Rightarrow k\leq \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\log_{10}{i} < k+1 \tag{2}$$
and, since $f(x)=\log_{10}{x}$ is ascending:
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\log_{10}{i}=
\sum\limits_{i=2}^{n}\left[i-(i-1)\right]\log_{10}{i}>\int\limits_{1}^{n}\log_{10}{x}dx
=\frac{x(\ln{x}-1)}{\ln{10}}\bigg\rvert_{1}^{n}=\frac{n(\ln{n}-1)+1}{\ln{10}} \tag{3}$$
Combining $(2)$ and $(3)$
$$\frac{n(\ln{n}-1)+1}{\ln{10}} < k+1 \tag{4}$$
In fact, for large enough $k$ we have an asymptotic 
$$\frac{n(\ln{n}-1)+1}{\ln{10}} \sim k$$
e.g. (applying numerical methods like [Newton's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) for example)
[$$\frac{n(\ln{n}-1)+1}{\ln{10}}=6 \Rightarrow n \approx 9$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7Bx(%5Cln%7Bx%7D-1)%2B1%7D%7B%5Cln%7B10%7D%7D%3D6)
[$$\frac{n(\ln{n}-1)+1}{\ln{10}}=3 \Rightarrow n \approx 6$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7Bx(%5Cln%7Bx%7D-1)%2B1%7D%7B%5Cln%7B10%7D%7D%3D3)